# Different Content Same Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

Situation:
I'm developing and application that sends email to a manager and cc's 1+ others.

Problem:
Is there a way to block content in an email based on recipient...?  There is a link that only the manager clicks on to get back to the application and a detailed record(no one else needs this link).  The link is the only difference in the emails.

Thanks

Suge.

Comment: The obvious question is: can't you send an additional email to the manager containing this link that rest of the people can't click?

Comment: That's one question but not the question...

Comment: If A and B receive two different things, two different things must be sent to A and B

Comment: I'm not looking for the obvious...  I'm looking for the "not so obvious" (a kinda outta the box thinking type thing)...  Since controls can be hidden on a webpage of which is html+... and the email is also HTML...

Comment: put some abstrracted <!--hidden--> identifiers in the email, if scriptable,  have the dudes email client detect these and do something with them

Comment: You have three options. 1) Include the link in the email to everyone, but include a message that the link is only for managers and make sure the page is password protected. 2) Send different emails to the manager or 3) Try some sort of crazy scripting thing, but it's likely to be difficult to implement and only work for specific email clients (IE, you *might* be able to get it to work in Outlook, but not in Outlook Web Access or iOS Mail)

Comment: Thanks Gents... I was hoping there was an email life cycle (somewhere near a webpage life cycle) where a developer could interact within the different phases...